# useState Not working when returning to a component after loading a separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a To Do list App in React. I have 3 Lists for the user to choose from. The issue I am having is when I add items to list #1, save and then move to a different list, when I return to list #1 and try to delete any items and save again and then go to another list and return it doesn't remember what I deleted and all the deleted items are back. But when I add items, save and delete what I want before leaving it works fine.

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt0e0.png)

(The first three items on each list are there by default that's not the issue I'm having.)

(Content.js) -->

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './Content.css';

export const Content = ({ list, listData, setData }) => {
    console.log('rendering', list);
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [toDoItems, setToDoItems] = useState(listData);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInputText(event.target.value);
    }

    const deleteItem = (event) => {
        event.target.parentElement.remove();
        setToDoItems(toDoItems.filter(item => item !== event.target.parentElement.value));
        console.log(toDoItems);
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        if (toDoItems.length != 0) {
            console.log('printing all items');
            const ol = document.querySelector('.toDoList');
            toDoItems.forEach(element => {
                const li = document.createElement('li');
                const button = document.createElement('button');
                button.classList.add('deleteButton');
                button.innerHTML = "<";
                button.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
                const textnode = document.createTextNode(element);
                li.appendChild(textnode);
                li.appendChild(button);
                ol.appendChild(li);
            });
        }
    }, []);
    

    const addItem = () => {
        if (inputText != '') {
            const ol = document.querySelector('.toDoList');
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('deleteButton');
            button.innerHTML = "<";
            button.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
            const textnode = document.createTextNode(inputText);
            button.setAttribute('value', textnode);
            li.appendChild(textnode);
            li.appendChild(button);
            ol.appendChild(li);
            setToDoItems(oldArray => [...oldArray, inputText]);
            document.querySelector('#addItems').value = '';
            setInputText('');
        }
    }

    const addItemAfterKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            addItem();
        }
    }

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        event.target.classList.toggle('done');
        console.log(toDoItems);
    }

    const saveButton = () => {
        setData(list, toDoItems);
        console.log('saving', toDoItems);
    }

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <div className="header">
                    <h1>{list}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="listContent">
                    <h2>To Do:</h2>
                    <div className="listItems ">
                            <ol onClick={handleClick} className="toDoList">
                                <li>Grab Coffee <button onClick={deleteItem} className="deleteButton" type="button">&#60;</button> </li>
                                <li>Make Breakfast <button onClick={deleteItem} className="deleteButton" type="button">&#60;</button> </li>
                                <li>Homework <button onClick={deleteItem} className="deleteButton" type="button">&#60;</button> </li>
                            </ol>
                    </div>
                    <div className="addItems">
                            <input onKeyDown={addItemAfterKeyDown} onChange={handleChange} type="text" id="addItems"/>
                            <br/>
                            <button onClick={addItem} className="addButton" type="button">Add Item</button>
                            <button onClick={saveButton} className="addButton" type="button">Save List</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

(App.js) -->

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navigation } from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import { Content } from './components/Content/Content';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const [route, setRoute] = useState('list1');
  const [list, setList] = useState('List #1');

  const [listData1, setlistData1] = useState([]);
  const [listData2, setlistData2] = useState([]);
  const [listData3, setlistData3] = useState([]);



  const routing = (list) => {
      if (list === 'list1') {
          setRoute(list);
          setList('List #1');
      } else if (list === 'list2') {
          setRoute(list);
          setList('List #2');
      } else if (list === 'list3') {
          setRoute(list);
          setList('List #3');
      }
  }

  const setData = (list, arrayData) => {
    if (list === 'List #1') {
        setlistData1(arrayData);
    } else if (list === 'List #2') {
        setlistData2(arrayData);
    } else if (list === 'List #3') {
        setlistData3(arrayData);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {route === 'list1' 
        ? <div className='App'>
          <Navigation routing={routing}/>
          <Content key='1' list={list} listData={listData1} setData={setData}/>
        </div> 
        : (route === 'list2'
        ? <div className='App'>
              <Navigation routing={routing}/>
              <Content key='2' list={list} listData={listData2} setData={setData}/>
          </div>
        : <div className='App'>
              <Navigation routing={routing}/>
              <Content key='3' list={list} listData={listData3} setData={setData}/>
          </div> 
          )
      }
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried deleting the specific items in the useState array but it only works when I stay on the page delete and then save. Not when I add, save, leave, come back and try to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is anti-react code you've written. You should almost never manipulate the DOM, you should just let your component render whatever it needs to based on current props/state.

The precise problem your running into here is not having a clear source of truth. `App` **owns** the state of listData, so `Content` should not contain it in it's state. It should render the data that is passed into it, and call the approprate callbacks that are also passed into it when it wants to change things and let the logic of updating the state happen wherever that state is owned (which is not in `Content`, but in `App`).

tl;dr - remove this from `Content`:

```
const [toDoItems, setToDoItems] = useState(listData);
```

and just let `Content` render `listData` and call `setData` when the user adds or removes an item with the newly updated list of items, and remove all the DOM manipulation code. It's parent (`App`) will update it's own state (the source of truth for `listData`), causing `App` to re-render `Content` with a new value for `listData` and let React worry about updating your DOM.

Comment: Thanks! I am now using map to loop over array and return list elements in the return of the content component, so no more dom manipulation